# X de millions de quelque chose, mais X mille de la même chose ?

Tags: grammaire, articles, nombres, de

Hier, je revisais quelque chose avec un tuteur, qui a repéré une erreur. J'avais écrit:

> une ville de 8 millions habitants.

alors que, apparemment, la forme correcte serait

> une ville de 8 millions **d'**habitants

Nous avons creusé un peu plus loin, et il s'est rendu compte qu'en fait la règle, il paraît, s'applique seulement avec millions, et pas avec mille, milliards, etc. Il est donc pour cela que je demande ici parce que pendant la leçon, nous n'avons pas pu trouver la raison qui explique ce cas.

**Concrètement** : est-ce que l'article « de » procède bien millions et pas mille, milliards, etc. ? Et si c'est le cas, pourquoi?

Answer (score 4):

La règle s'applique pour tous les nombres qui sont considérés comme des approximations, et donc aussi avec *milliard* :

- *Une planète de huit milliards d'habitants.*
- *Deux milliers d'habitants sont partis de la ville.*
- *C'est un village d'une centaine d'habitants.*
- *Seul(e/s) une douzaine d'habitants n'(a/ont) pas voté.*

Ceci entraîne la différence observée entre les deux phrases suivantes :

> — Ça coûte mille euros. (valeur précise)
> — Ça coûte un millier d'euros. (valeur approximative)

Si on souhaite indiquer une valeur précise avec les grands nombres, il faut passer par la notation scientifique :

> Il y aura bientôt 8 x 10<sup>9</sup> habitants sur terre. (et pas « d'habitants »)

Référence: [OQLF](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1647)

Comment: Et comment prononcer 8 x 10^9? :)

Comment: @Luke *huit dix puissance neuf habitants* !